# Pentaho data integration merge with inner join has 5000+ matches and left join has 0 matches

Tags: sorting, merge, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I want to merge an excel with a database query to add some fields in a transformations.

The merge with INNER seems to work well and has +5000 matches, but I need to do a LEFT JOIN to get the unmatches rows as well, and in this case the matched rows is 0.

Why is not matching any rows when LEFT JOIN is used? Any ideas?

**Transformation**

[image]

**Merge**

[image]

**Sort rows (left side)**

[image]

**Sort rows (right side)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it looks fine but I'm unsure why the `Merge join` step didn't work for you maybe you can try another way to do left join by using the `Stream lookup` step instead, for me it works both ways. You can find the difference between the two steps from [here](https://helicaltech.com/what-is-a-lookup-how-is-it-different-from-the-merge-join-component-in-etl/)

[image: Merge join]

[image: Stream lookup]